# java script using array to store conditions

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement, conditional-statements

**How to add if condition statements into array (java script)**

I'm having issues with storing condition statements in array. I can get the code to run, but i'm getting unexpected results. The aim of this section is to find the state name from user input box. Then check the post code input box to check if the postcode is within that states postcode range.

**iv simplified the code so its easy to understand but still runs into the same error

Since X has value of 1000 is should not pass as true on both array index values, but for some reason it does. It may be very simple fix but im  really confused as to why its not working. Sorry this is my first unit in javascript so im not expert by any means.

```js
function x()
{

    var x = 1000;
  
    var conditionArray = [
        (2000 <= x < 3000),
        (6000 <= x < 7000)
  ];
    
    var i =0;
    
    while (conditionArray.length > i)
    {
            // x for some reason is always passed as true
            if (conditionArray[i])
            {
                alert("within range");
            } 
            else
            {
    alert("not within range");
            }
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: A while loop to iterate over an array? Why?

Comment: Why not? How is it against the rule?

Comment: `2000 <= x && x < 3000`

Comment: It's probably not a good idea to completely rewrite the question after people have started to answer it, btw.

Comment: sorry, people had really hard time understand what i was trying to get across. I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now that you've refined your post, try this:

```
    function x () {
      var
        x = 1000,
        i = 0,
        conditionals = [
          (x >= 2000 && x < 3000),
          (x >= 6000 && x < 7000)
        ];

      while (conditionals.length > i) {
        // x for some reason is always passed as true.
        if (conditionals[i]) {
          alert('Within range');
        } else {
          alert('Not within range');
        }
        i += 1;
      }
    }
```

You're writing your boolean expressions incorrectly. This is mathematically okay, but in JS you need to consider each evaluation as two concerns, if you want to know whether the value is within a range.

Written this way, you can see clearly that 1000 is not between 2000 and 3000 and it is also not between 6000 and 7000. So they both evaluate to `false`. If you were getting both values to be `true`, in your original example, it may have been because of a similar misevaluation.

Comment: Also, why is the comment concerning `x` being written within the `while` loop? Nothing involving `x` is being addressed in there.

Comment: You're welcome. You can close the thread by choosing the best answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have returned `postcodeNameBoolean` instead of `postcodeNumberBoolean`.

Comment: I fixed the name, but its not my main problem.  thanks though

Comment: You still are assigning the `true` value to `postcodeNameBoolean` and returning `postcodeNumberBoolean`

Comment: thanks, Iv renamed variables a few times and missed those as i havn't started that phase of the process yet. My main concern is why conditions in array are giving incorrect responses.

Answer (score 0):

Some revisions:

- `stateSelected` (which, below, is renamed to `selectedState`) is undefined.
- `validChangeInputStyle` is misspelled in the original post.
- Remove explaining the data type from variable names. It's bad practice. (e.g., something**Array**, something**Integer**, etc.)
- Prefix string representations of numbers with the `+` operator to transform them into instances of the `Number` constructor. Make sure the operator touches the variable name.
- Place opening block braces on same line as declaration.
- Write `else {` on the same line as the `if`'s closing brace.
- Use `var` only once per scope.
- Set a space before and after function parentheses when defining a function. Only let the parentheses touch the function name when applying the function.
- `zipcodeNumber` (previously, `postcodeNumberBoolean`) was being returned in the `if` and the `else` blocks, so it is factored out to be below the conditional--written once.
- Using the `++` operator to increment a number by `1` is syntactical (and sometimes misused) sugar for `i += 1`--which is also sugar for `i = i + 1`. So the fewer abstractions you make on what you mean, the better. The `+=` has more intent. However, many will debate this.

Some questions for you to answer to, hopefully, help us with solving the problem:

- What is the purpose of `zipcodeNumber`?
- Aren't zip codes five digits in length? Why is there equality testing to make sure it's between four-digit numbers?
- What is the purpose of the `while` loop? Are you deliberately not using a `for` loop?
- Can you please just expand on the end goal? There may be a clearer way to write this that we can work on together.

  ```
  function matchZipcode () {
    var
      statePatterns = [
        /(nsw|new\ssouth\swales)/gi,
        /(qld|queensland)/gi,
        /(vic|victoria)/gi,
        /(act|australian\scapital\sterritory)/gi,
        /(tas|tasmania)/gi,
        /(nt|northern\sterritory)/gi,
        /(sa|south\saustralia)/gi,
        /(wa|western\australia)/gi
      ],
      zipcodeRanges = [
        (2000 <= zipcodeInput < 3000),
        (4000 <= zipcodeInput < 5000)
      ],
      zipcodeNumber = false,
      error = 'Error: post code does not match selected state.',
      zipcodeInput = +document.getElementById('postcode-input').value,
      i = 0;

    while (statePatterns.length > i) {
      if (statePatterns[i].test(selectedState)) {
        if (zipcodeRanges[i]) {
          alert('within range');
          zipcodeNumber = true;
          validChangeInputStyle('postcode', 'postcode');
        } else {
          invalidResponse('postcode', error, 'postcode');
        }
        return zipcodeNumber;
      }
      i += 1;
    }
  }
  ```

Comment: post codes are different in Australia they are 4 digits. Sorry this is just one small part of a much larger code. I'm basically just trying to work out how to get conditions into array to test a value using a loop.  Iv just updated the code to make it more easy to understand my aim.